# как разделить список в Питоне на одинаковые отрывки

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

Задача такова, получаю данные картинки через PIL - `list(img.getdata())`
Нужно их переслать через SPI - максимум могу послать `list(img.getdata())[:4000]`, то есть 4000 байт.

Как заставить или написать в Python, чтобы он послал все данные?

Python 2.7, Raspberry Pi

Comment: @jfs через SPI вы их не перешлете. Ну и мой чип не сможет их показать тогда

Comment: @jfs мой чип принимает это все, если есть header, color palette и data от картинки. У JPEG, это насколько я знаю, отсутствует.

Comment: @jfs ответ ниже, мне должен уже подойти. Мне ответили что мне нужно.

Comment: @jfs я задал вопрос о том, как разделить эти данные, мне ответили. Остальное как вы просите, совсем не по теме. Вопрос и Ответ, подходят идеально. Не нужно сразу минусовать вопрос!

Comment: related: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вам нужно разбить картинку на чанки по 4000 байт, и отсылать эти чанки. Сделать это можно так:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

data = list(img.getdata())
for chunk in chunks(data, 4000):
    send(chunk)
```